# If file exist returns else note

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code:

```
if(file_exists("../media/books/$oldcover")) {
    unlink("../media/books/$oldcover");
} else { 
    //do nothing 
}
```

Why does the *if* works good and the else returns this annoying note: **Unlink(../media/books/) [function.unlink]: Is a directory in (path...)**

I want the else doing nothing.

Comment: It's the 'then' that is producing the warning: you are trying to delete a directory (`../media/books`), probably because `$oldcover` is empty.

Comment: delete the else, if it does not do anything, you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your `$oldcover` variable could be empty and thus is checking if the directory exists or not.

This then tries to `unlink` the directory instead. Perhaps you should try this:

```
if($oldcover && file_exists("../media/books/$oldcover")) {
  unlink("../media/books/$oldcover");
} else { 
  //do nothing 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears your variable `$oldcover` is empty. You could also change the conditional to check if the file exists and that it is not a directory.

```
if(file_exists("../media/books/$oldcover") && !is_dir("../media/books/$oldcover"))
```